# space between border and text in span

Tags: html, css, border

I need to have a **span** (within a p) with border-bottom followed by a regular **p** which has also a border-bottom. I want to have both borders have the same space between them. That means I want to make the span-element larger so the border will move down.

Now, with small span-elements I could just use display:inline-block. But I have long reflowing text and using inline-block removes the border from the text.

Here's an example of what I intend. I want the (second) red line move down on the height of the first black one.

```css
p {border-bottom: 1px solid black;
line-height: 2em;
margin:0;
}
span {border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p><span>My bottom-border really needs to be lower. This way it's just ugly and I hate how I can't just move my span-border around a bit without using display:block or inline-block. Booohoooo </span></p>
<p>bla</p>
<p>bla</p>
<p>bla</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add some padding to the span

```css
p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}

span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p><span>My bottom-border really needs to be lower. This way it's just ugly and I hate how I can't just move my span-border around a bit without using display:block or inline-block. Booohoooo </span></p>
<p>bla</p>
<p>bla</p>
<p>bla</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please add and modify the css and html code as given below.

**HTML:**

```
<p class="with_red_border"><span>My bottom-border really needs to be lower. This way it's just ugly and I hate how I can't just move my span-border around a bit without using display:block or inline-block. Booohoooo </span></p>
<p>bla</p>
<p>bla</p>
<p>bla</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin:0;
}
span {
    border:none;
}
.with_red_border {
    position: relative;
}
.with_red_border::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: red;
    height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really work. Anyway, the padding solution from Temani works well enough.

Comment: Its ok.. but how my code is not working for you.. i tested myself

Comment: Have u added class for p tag.. classname is "with_red_border"

Comment: I just copied what you wrote in jsfiddle